# Node type checking / 'coerced to a string'?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Newly to Node.js i would have known how node types really working ...

I'm currently working on files, just to have an example take a look at this function :

```
fs.write(fd, data[, position[, encoding]], callback)
```

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback), data should be of types :

```
data <String> | <Buffer>
```

but next it's specified

```
If data is not a Buffer instance then the value will be coerced to a string.
```

**1 /**
I'm asking if **data** paramater accepted types is pure speculation and it could be of any type like: `Object | MyOwnObject` ?

**2 /**
In this case, what means ***'coerced to a string'*** ? I mean, Is it calling a *toString()* method of my object ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `data` parameter is neither a `Buffer` nor a `String`, it is coerced by adding the empty string to it:

```
if (typeof buffer !== 'string')
    buffer += '';
```

This is equivalent to

```
buffer = String(buffer) + '';
```

In many cases, this will end up calling `buffer.toString()`.

Source: [the source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v6.2.1/lib/fs.js#L758)